# webkit.messageHandlers for React to inject JavaScript to Swift

Tags: javascript, swift, reactjs, wkwebview

I'm working with WKWebView, where I'm loading a webpage (React) to display. But my didFinish is getting triggered too early. So when my delegate notify about didFinish, then I do only see a white screen for a couple of seconds, before the actual data is loaded.

> This is not working, causes white screen - before showing actual content

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {  
    activityIndicator?.stopAnimating()
}
```

Instead I read this article, telling me it should be possible to achieve, by letting the webpage, notify the Swift code when loaded.

https://medium.com/capital-one-developers/javascript-manipulation-on-ios-using-webkit-2b1115e7e405

I did implement the following code, in my Xcode project

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let userContentController = WKUserContentController()
    userContentController.add(self, name: "test")
}

extension DashboardViewController: WKScriptMessageHandler {
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if message.name == "test", let messageBody = message.body as? String {
            print(messageBody)
        }
    }
}
```

But, now we are here. I don't know where to put this, since my web app is written in React.

```
<script>   
    function printHelloWorld() {
        window.webkit.messageHandlers.test.postMessage("Did finish loading");   
    }   

    window.onload = printHelloWorld; 
</script>
```

My React component

```
class Page extends React.Component<{ location, match }> {

    public render() {
        const content = (
            <div className="row">
              <p>Content</p>
            </div>
        );

        return (
            content
        )
    }
}

export default Page;
```

Can anyone tell me, how I can use `window.webkit.messageHandlers.test.postMessage` within my React component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try calling the function when the component mounts:

```
class Page extends React.Component<{ location, match }> {

    componentDidMount() {
        window.webkit.messageHandlers.test.postMessage("Did finish loading");
    }
    render() {
      ...
    }
}
```

It's sort of the *onload* for a React component.

More info about [componentdidmount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentDidMount)

Comment: I already tried that solution. But it seems like everything works, if I just type (windows as any) instead!
I'll approve your answer. Thanks for leading me back on track.

Comment: You are right. `window.onload = printHelloWorld;` will also work. 
Running the command from the React component can help you control the moment it gets run. 
Everything you know about javascript also works alongside React.